# Create time series in R with data for week days only

Tags: r, time-series

I have a data set containing the energy usage by day (date) from 01 Jan 2016 through to 07 Nov 2017 on a daily basis. One of the fields therein is a flag for non working day (nwd) with values of 0 and 1 indicating whether or not this is a working day.

The structure of the data looks like this :-

```
Date,usage,avgtemp,nwd
2016-01-01,28.5,105986,1
2016-01-02,29.2,105548,1
.
.
.
2017-11-07,98457,23.5,0
```

I created a data frame with these values - no problems. I then created 2 other data frames, one with nwd = 1 and other with nwd = 1 for the data set for non working and working days respectively.

I am trying to generate a time series (using zoo or xts package - I am open to either) for each of these 2 data frames so that I can then do the non stationarity tests (adf/pp) on them and then do the arima modelling to build a forecast model of the usage.

Can I use a time series for such data sets where the data is not quite regular because each of these series will have gaps - the work day series may have less than 5 continuous days in a week if there are holidays in between. The same would apply to the non working day series.

I cannot summarize this at a weekly level as I need to forecast them at a daily level and possibly at the half hourly level subsequently. I might even want to do 'ardl' modelling later using 'avgtemp' as one of the regressors.

P.S.
Found a post which to some extent is similar to mine but I can't seem to get it going based on the responses there :-

[how to convert data frame into time series in R](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29046311/how-to-convert-data-frame-into-time-series-in-r)

Comment: `read.csv.zoo("myfile") `and `read.zoo(myDataFrame)` will convert such data to zoo.  If your analysis functions require regularly spaced values and `z` is a zoo series with dates then `zoo(coredata(z))` will give a zoo series with index values of 1, 2, 3, ... which you can later map back if need be.

Comment: I checked it and it does just that - not that I doubted it. How would I then use this zoo object (which is not padded with the non working or holiday) dates for my arima() modelling in R - because isn't it that it would require the object to be a time series? Or is it preferable to have those missing non working dates padded before using this for modelling purposes.

Comment: If your analysis function requires a `ts` series then `as.ts(z)` where `z` is a zoo object will create one.