# Covert R dataframe to timeseries

Tags: r

I am new to ML/timeseries so not sure if this question is very basic.
Have the following dataframe:
week 1,1,1,1,,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,3,3,3,3,4,4...(1 - 145 weeks) numOrder 120,110,100.....
There is no set frequency i.e the number of records for each week can be same of different
how do I convert this dataframe to timeseries object 
A simple tm=ts(dataframe name) give "mts","ts",matrix with week as column1 and numOrder as column 2. but a plot of plot(tm[,2]) gives a time series but x axis does not show time as weeks (1,2,3) 
please guide how to convert this dataframe to timeseries object

Comment: How about this one :  [How to convert data frame into time series?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29046311/how-to-convert-data-frame-into-time-series)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to convert data frame into time series?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29046311/how-to-convert-data-frame-into-time-series)