# What am I doing wrong in converting my data frame into xts for time series analysis?

Tags: r, date, dataframe, time-series, xts

My `data frame` is called  'mydata' and it has only 2 columns and looks as follows:

```
Date          Sales
2016-07-01    51256
2016-08-01    75892
2016-09-01    67115
...
```

Running the following code `str(mydata)` gives me the following:

```
'data.frame':   28 obs. of  2 variables:
 $ DATE  : chr  "2016-07-01" "2016-08-01" "2016-09-01" ...
 $ PKGREV: num   51256 75892 67115 ...
```

I have the following libraries loaded in R:

```
library(ggplot2)
library(dplyr)
library(scales)
library(ggthemes)
library(magrittr)
library(h2o)
library(timetk)
library(tidyquant)
```

I understand that I need to convert the 'Date' column into dates first before doing the `xts` conversion.
From the 2 Stackoverflow questions below (see links below), I have made these 2 attempts:

Attempt 1:

```
 mydata2 <- xts(mydata[,-1], order.by=mydata[,1])    


Error message: 

Error in xts(mydata[, -1], order.by = mydata[, 1]) : 
order.by requires an appropriate time-based object
```

Attempt 2:

```
mydata2 <- xts(mydata[, -1], order.by=as.POSIXct(mydata$Date))

Error message: 

 Error in as.POSIXct.default(mydata$Date) : 
 do not know how to convert 'mydata$Date' to class “POSIXct”
```

StackOverflow questions consulted:

[Converting a data frame to xts](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4297231/converting-a-data-frame-to-xts)

[Converting data.frame to xts order.by requires an appropriate time-based object](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23224142/converting-data-frame-to-xts-order-by-requires-an-appropriate-time-based-object)

What am I missing here?

Comment: Did you try with running `mydata$Date <- as.Date(mydata$Date)` first?

Comment: When I run the code you mention, I get the following error message:"Error in as.Date.default(mydata$Date) : 
  do not know how to convert 'mydata$Date' to class “Date”

Comment: Please review [mcve].

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the `ymd` function from the `lubridate` package to convert strings to dates. Then you can use `tk_xts` from `timetk`

```
library(dplyr)
library(timetk)
library(lubridate)

mydata %>% 
  mutate(Date = ymd(Date)) %>% 
  tk_xts(select = Sales)
```

Comment: I get the following message when running the code:
Using column `DATE` for date_var.
Warning message:
In tk_xts_.data.frame(data = data, select = select, date_var = date_var,  :
  Non-numeric columns being dropped: DATE

Comment: The warning it's not an issue. I edited the answer selecting the column so you will not see the warning anymore.

Comment: Thanks. However my issue now is that the first column after converting to xts does not have a header. I still need the column to have the header 'Date'.
Message when I now run the code:
Using column `DATE` for date_var.

Comment: As far as I know you cannot have a name for the index of an `xts` object. why you need it? Maybe I can try to come up with a different solution.

Comment: I need it to be able to perform a visualization on the data before proceeding with my analysis.

Comment: Do you need to plot the time series for different time windows?

Comment: I need to plot the time series for the whole period and see if there are any seasonality or pattern present in the data.

Comment: To be clearer, I am following this example to perform some machine learning techniques on my data:
https://www.r-bloggers.com/demo-week-time-series-machine-learning-with-h2o-and-timetk/

Answer (score 0):

A few comments on the question:

- It seems you did not convert the time index to `"Date"` class -- you could alternately use `"yearmon"` class if the data is monthly.
- regarding attempt 2, you should NOT use `"POSIXt"` for date data.  That will expose you to the possibility of timezone coding errors unnecessarily.  Such errors can be subtle and therefore hard to detect. If you do use `"POSIXt"` anyways then use `"POSIXct"` class and not `"POSIXlt"` class.
- based on your comment there are aspects of the data that you did not show in the question. Below we have provided a self-contained reproducible example and two alternative sets of code which both work.  You will need to determine how your setup differs from that.

To keep the solutions below self-contained we use `Lines` as defined in the Note at the end but you could replace `text=Lines` with your filename, e.g. `"mydata.dat"`.

The first alternative below uses `read.zoo` to read the data into a `"zoo"` class object which is then converted to an `"xts"` class object.  `read.zoo` will automatically convert the first column to `"Date"` class (unless you use arguments specifying otherwise). The zoo package is automatically loaded by the xts package.

The second alternative below reads the data into a data frame `DF` and then uses `xts()` converting its second argument to `"Date"` class.

```
library(xts)

# 1
z <- read.zoo(text = Lines, header = TRUE)
as.xts(z)

# 2
DF <- read.table(text = Lines, header = TRUE)
with(DF, xts(Sales, as.Date(Date)))
```

**yearmon**

If you wanted to use `"yearmon"` class rather than `"Date"` class then in the first alternative use

```
x <- read.zoo(text = Lines, header = TRUE, FUN = as.yearmon)
```

and in the second:

```
with(DF, xts(Sales, as.yearmon(Date)))
```

**Note:** The input, `Lines`, in reproducible form is:

```
Lines <- "
Date          Sales
2016-07-01    51256
2016-08-01    75892
2016-09-01    67115"
```